# How can I change admin port?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, port

When trying to run an application it doesn't, log says port 8000 already occupied checked netstat and the pid is system (system listening on port 8000) can't exactly kill that process. My only option is to change the port for the admin.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `--admin_port=8001` argument. See the docs for others: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Command-line_arguments